# Hiding and showing elements with their respective styles in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide an element with `display: none` using javascript and then show it again. However, if I hide a default `<li>` element  and then try to show it using `display: block`, it no longer uses its styles set previously by the default `display: list-item` property.

The same applies to other styles as well: if one element has the `display: inline-block` property and the other has `display: list-item`, after hiding and showing then with javascript both of them would have `display: block` set, which would have an effect in the styling of the elements.

How do I hide and show elements so that their display values are "remembered" when showing them with javascript?

My suggestion: maybe it is possible to load the value from the css file using javascript? And if the display value is not specifically set, we can safely use `display: block` to show the element. This would solve the problem.

Please don't suggest jQuery here. I'm developing my own framework and learning how to do it myself has additional value.

Comment: how are you hiding and showing the element? show us the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display` property can only have one value, so if you set it to `none` and then want to restore it to its previous value, the only way to do that is to remember the previous value somewhere so you can restore it.

You can store the prior attribute as a property of the object itself if you want.

```
function hide(obj) {
    if (obj.style.display != "none") {
        // save original display value
        // if we are not already hidden
        obj.priorDisplay = obj.style.display;
        obj.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function show(obj) {
    var val = "block";
    if (obj.priorDisplay) {
        val = obj.priorDisplay;
    }
    obj.style.display = val;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that, but I still think that there has to be another way. What about my suggestion?

Comment: @doitmyway - I don't understand your suggestion or how it would be simpler than the code I've offered.

Comment: I thought about loading the display property from the css styles of the document.

Comment: @doitmyway - and why is that easier or more general purpose than this?  How would you know what CSS rule in the CSS is the right one?

Comment: Fair enough. Your solution seems simple enough. Now when I think of it, I guess I'll stick to using style.display to set the visibility of an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var oldDisplay = document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID").style.display;

function callHide(id) {
   var element= document.getElementById(id);
   element.style.display = "none";
}

function callShow(id) {
   var element= document.getElementById(id);
   if (oldDisplay == "none") {
      element.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      element.style.display = oldDisplay;
   }
}
```

**Your suggestion:**

> My suggestion: maybe it is possible to load the value from the css
>   file using javascript? And if the display value is not specifically
>   set, we can safely use display: block to show the element. This would
>   solve the problem.

I don't think it will be that easy to load the styles either by reading the .css files or parsing it or if any other possible solution available

I would rather suggest you to just save the `display` value into a variable and use it while you need to show it, it will consume less line of code, less clients system memory and process and it will also put less burden on the user's browser